# Why does the python code calculate a very large variance for the lognormal distribution

Tags: python, variance, economics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCUkQ.png)The final answer is Income y: Mean = 2484.87, Variance = 5650460.07, Gini = 0.4295
Consumption c: Mean = 2236.54, Variance = 2373130.74, Gini = 0.3159
I don't think this is correct.
I want to verify that for an exponential normal distribution, the variance should be this large, and if not, how should I go about modifying it?
Thanks so much.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i77956833/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why do you think that the `numpy.var()` implementation is incorrect? I think it highly unlikely that it's managed to get through decades of review and use without someone recognizing a flaw.

Comment: Compute the square of the mean to get a rough idea of size. The variance looks entirely appropriate. Perhaps you want the standard deviation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that it is the logarithm of y that has a normal distribution with mean `mu` and variance `sigma^2`; y itself can then be very large.

The mean of the lognormal distribution is `exp(mu+sigma^2/2)` and the variance is `exp(2.mu+sigma^2)*(exp(sigma^2)-1)`. With your parameters (`mu=7.5` and `sigma=0.8`) this gives `mean=2489.9` and `variance=5557849`.

This is perfectly in line with your statistics for y. So - no worries!

BTW: please give code samples as code samples, not images.